# Social Instagram activity on Facebook is split between the timeline post and the expanded picture

Tags: facebook, instagram

My friend and I both use Instagram for iOS. When we post a picture, there is an option to share it on Facebook. We both have the Facebook timeline enabled.

When she posts a picture, she and her friends can write comments under the post. When you click on the picture to expand it, those same comments are there.

When *I* post a picture, however, the conversation is split. The comments made under the post are not the same as the comments made under the expanded pic. This also happens to a second friend of mine. We don't like this behavior.

As far as I know, there is only one way to configure Facebook integration within Instagram, so I can't for the life of me figure out the difference between our setups. Has anyone else experienced this? How do I change my setup so that it mirrors the behavior of my friend's?

Comment: I just realized that it might have been an Instagram update. A photo that I posted on March 28 did not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: that's actually what I was going to suggest. The first thing I suggest usually is to uninstall the Facebook application and re-authorize it from the site/app that requests it. Kind of the new "Turn it off an on again" but it works 95%* of the time. *non-scientific

Comment: I uninstalled both apps and also removed Instagram in the Facebook > Settings > Account Settings > Apps and Websites section of the iPhone app. The behavior still existed when I reauthorized. Oh well, thank you!

Comment: I have also seen the same behavior. The other thing is that the photo can't be highlighted anymore. Facebook bought Instagram and the integration got worse. Interesting, to say the least.

Comment: Just noticed this behavior, as well. It's a function of there being separate comments/likes on "this activity from Instagram" versus comments/like on "this photo" (since the Instagram photos now get automatically put in a gallery).  It's because the story is "Dan took a photo with Instagram" instead of "Dan added a photo to this Instagram gallery". Would expect that this get fixed soon now that Instagram IS Facebook.